# What is the best way to store sensitive data that only the app can access?

Tags: firebase, salesforce

In my app, I use a rest API to connect to an online web service. For this, I use sensitive data like username password but also some keys. You can see the problem when someone decompiles my app and sees the sensitive data in my code. I am using Firebase in my app. My question is what the best way could be to store sensitive data. Remember that this is the same for all devices and the info would be around 5 strings. Things I have found online are: using Firebase Database with security rules (this would be ideal but I cant get it to work for only my app), using the last pixels of a picture to store strings. Specifically, I am using Salesforce as my web service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use username/password for your app to connect to Salesforce. Use oAuth instead and then you don't need to worry about storing passwords. You can also look at encrypting the key fields using shared keys. Your Salesforce app can decrypt the data using the encryption classes OOTB.